# PostgreSQL 9.2 10x slower than MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 and MySQL 5.5 (InnoDB) installed on my laptop.
Both database engines using default installation and populated from the same CSV file.
I have 'sales_reports' table with ca. 700K rows.

**Scenario 1:**

- following query:

  > select name, year, region, branch from sales_reports group by name,
  >   year, region, branch;
- PostgreSQL 9.2: Total query runtime: 42.14 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- PostgreSQL explain:

  ```
  Group  (cost=165091.16..174275.61 rows=73476 width=58) (actual time=35196.959..41896.739 rows=18064 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=165091.16..166928.05 rows=734756 width=58) (actual time=35196.956..41704.549 rows=734756 loops=1)
      Sort Key: name, year, region, branch
      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 49920kB
      ->  Seq Scan on sales_reports  (cost=0.00..38249.56 rows=734756 width=58) (actual time=0.048..282.331 rows=734756 loops=1)
  Total runtime: 41906.628 ms
  ```
- MySQL 5.5 : Total query runtime: 4.4 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- MySQL explain:

  ```
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | sales_reports | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 729433 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  ```
- **PostgreSQL 10x times slower**

**Scenario 2:**

- following query:

  ```
  select name, year, region, branch, sum(sale) as sale from sales_reports group by name, year, region, branch;
  ```
- PostgreSQL 9.2: Total query runtime: 42.51 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- PostgreSQL explain:

  ```
  GroupAggregate  (cost=165091.16..176847.26 rows=73476 width=64) (actual time=35160.911..42254.060 rows=18064 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=165091.16..166928.05 rows=734756 width=64) (actual time=35160.489..41857.986 rows=734756 loops=1)
      Sort Key: name, year, region, branch
      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 54760kB
      ->  Seq Scan on sales_reports  (cost=0.00..38249.56 rows=734756 width=64) (actual time=0.047..296.347 rows=734756 loops=1)
  Total runtime: 42264.790 ms
  ```
- MySQL 5.5 : Total query runtime: 8.15 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- MySQL explain:

  ```
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | sales_reports | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 729433 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  ```
- **PostgreSQL 5x times slower**

**Scenario 3:**

- following query:

  ```
  select name, year, region, sum(sale) as sale from sales_reports group by name, year, region;
  ```
- PostgreSQL 9.2: Total query runtime: 1 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- PostgreSQL explain:

  ```
  HashAggregate  (cost=45597.12..45655.62 rows=5850 width=37) (actual time=758.396..759.756 rows=4644 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on sales_reports  (cost=0.00..38249.56 rows=734756 width=37) (actual time=0.061..116.541 rows=734756 loops=1)
  Total runtime: 760.133 ms
  ```
- MySQL 5.5 : Total query runtime: 5.8 sec, 18064 rows retrieved
- MySQL explain:

  ```
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | sales_reports | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 729433 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
  +----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
  ```
- **PostgreSQL 5x times faster**

Any ideas why first two scenarios are so slow on PostgreSQL?

BTW, I created indexes for fields I'm using in the query on PostgreSQL, I didn't create any indexes on MySQL.

Thanks,

Marek

Comment: Show `explain analyze` from PostgreSQL, and `explain` from MySQL. Compare table sizes. Compare I/O stats. Edit your question to add the info. Also be specific about how you're measuring the timings. See also https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Have you tried to run ANALYZE on your PostgreSQL database ? Maybe it's choosing a bad strategy for your query.

Comment: Are you running this from a psql/mysql console directly on the machine?

Comment: Oh, and are you using MyISAM with MySQL? Because if I strapped a big rocket motor on and didn't worry about little details like seatbelts or parachutes, I'd be faster than a nice safe plane too.

Comment: Maybe caching involved? Did you run the statement *multiple* times on both DBMS? Also did you change the memory settings for Postgres? The defaults are *extremely* cautious and should almost always be raised.

Comment: When talking performance, it's all in the details. And most of the important details are not in your question - which is therefore pointless as it stands. "Default" settings are basically useless for a larger DB. You have to [work on the setup](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config.html)

Comment: @CraigRinger added explain results

Comment: @CraigRinger: MySQL with InnoDB, I'm looking at pgAdmin messages and console result to measure the time

Comment: @jishi: I'm running this from pdAdmin (PostgreSQL) and from console (MySQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no caching involved, second query on MySQL takes always 0.0 sec

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter what details do you need?

Comment: Nothing in your analyzes for Postgres shows index usage, which makes me think that you don't have indexes, or don't have correct indexes, or haven't run `ANALYZE` on the table so that the index gets used.  But no, Postgres used correctly isn't going to take 10x as long to get similar results as MySQL.

Comment: @marek: Table definition, index definition, .. Indexes are obviously not used - though, while retrieving the whole table, they can only help with sorting. But you'll hardly want the whole table in real life ... First work on your basic setup, before we spend more time on this. Default setup for PostgreSQL is mostly useless, because it is aimed at the casual user with very conservative settings. Start by reading the [Postgres Wiki on Performance Optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization). If your findings don't change after that, come back for more.

Comment: you should include the `explain analyze` output, not just `explain`

Comment: is `branch` a long-ish text field? which locale/collation is the database using? try increasing the `work_mem` setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Default postgresql config is rather conservative. For starters, try increasing `shared_buffers` to 1GB. (Remember about restarting the server for the change to take effect.)

Also, try increasing `work_mem` until the GroupAggregate switches to HashAggregate in the explain. You can change this without a restart.

A word of warning: Before messing with the settings in production, please read the friendly manual, there are some gotchas involved.

Comment: thanks, set work_mem = '15MB'; did the job. Explain shows HashAggregate and the total query runtime is now 2880 ms. Cheers!

Comment: Good point on the tuning. I'd forgotten about that because the first thing I do is usually throw that out.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. When making indexes on varchar/text columns (like name probably is) it may be faster to use a hash-type index in PostgreSQL for the group by statements
2. If mysql is using MyISAM tables it'll likely be faster for non concurrent loads because MyISAM ignores a lot of safety things that InnoDB and PgSQL have.
3. You should try vacuum analyze on your pgsql db.
4. You may want to create a composite index on name, year, region, branch to make that group by portion faster.

Comment: In addition to these suggestions, also check the memory configuration of PostgreSQL.  The defaults are much more conservative.  Another thing that may help is the use of "cluster" in pg which sorts the table by an index.

Comment: An hash index is not faster than a btree, don't use it at all.